# Verify rdf:Container(rdf:Seq) using shacl constraints

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs, turtle-rdf, shacl

I am currently trying to build a constraint validation shape for an incoming object of the type `rdf:Seq`. The `shacl` shapes I have used, use the path to identify triple and then add additional constraint validations on datatype, length and count. But, with the case of `rdf:Seq` the predicate is a variable, it can be rdf:_1, rdf:_2,.... . How can I build an effective shape where I would not know how many elements would be present in the incoming `rdf:Seq` object?

Or is there a way I can check that if the predicate is of the type `rdfs:ContainerMembershipProperty` I can validate the `datatype` of the data, otherwise ignore it?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Let's say for a given incoming data

```
...
<incoming node> schema:colors _:blankNode1 .
_:blankNode1 rdf:type rdf:Seq .
_:blankNode1 rdf:_1 "Red" .
_:blankNode1 rdf:_2 "Blue" .
_:blankNode1 rdf:_3 "Yello" .
...
```

What could the shape be?
I was trying the following

```
...
sh: property [
   sh:path schema:colors ;
   sh:class rdf:Seq ;
   sh:property [ 
       sh:path <ideally would like a regex here> ;
       # or a way to identify the path to data tripe
       sh:in ("Red" "Blue" "Green" ) ;
   ] ;
 ] ;
...
```

Comment: Or are there partial path validators?

Comment: can i do `sh:path ( [ dash:stem rdf:_ ; ] ) ;` ?